# tesseract.exe is not installed or it's not in your path

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I am using Pytesseract to read a specific part of a PDF. Following is my code to configure tesseract into my code.

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = os.path.join(cwd, "Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe")
```

*cwd* is the same directory where my SplitPDF.py file and the Tesseract-OCR (which contains tesseract.exe) folder are present.

When I execute SplitPDF.py everything works fine and I have my desired output.
But the problem occurs when I create SplitPDF.exe (using Pyinstaller) I am getting an error that says tesseract.exe is not installed or it's not in your path.

Following is the complete error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 223, in run_tesseract
>   File "subprocess.py", line 775, in **init**   File "subprocess.py",
>   line 1178, in _execute_child FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The
>   system cannot find the file specified
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File "tkinter__init__.py", line
>   1705, in **call** File "PDF_Splitter.py", line 241, in UploadAction1
>   pdfsplitbylca(entryString) File "Split_by_LCA_1.py", line 155, in
>   pdfsplitbylca text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang = 'eng')
>   File "site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 345, in
>   image_to_string File "site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line
>   344, in  File "site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line
>   253, in run_and_get_output File
>   "site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 225, in run_tesseract
>   pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError:
>   C:\Users\VADIRA~1.KAT\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI370202\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe
>   is not installed or it's not in your path

Am I not creating the .exe correctly or is there a better way to configure Tesseract?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the `Pytesseract` library (tesseract python library) instead of the executable. I hope this helped. The usage is pretty easy. you will have to install it first but to use

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('image'))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I am unable to use this way, because i can't install pytesseract on my windows using pip. So I will have to manually install it. As it is not defined in the global variables I am using the pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd to configure it.